# Placing widgets directly beneath a Row widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to build a calendar for my app in flutter. I have a list of text widgets that are set to all weekdays from Monday to Sunday like S M T W and so on and I also have a list of widgets called buttons (which displays the date) which I'd like to place right beneath the weekday text inside a wrap widget, so that it wraps to next line when it runs out of space. the list of text widgets is then fed to a row widget which i have placed in my Scaffold's body property like so:

```
body: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: <Widget>[
    //days is the list<widget>
    for(Widget day in days)
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 70, 0, 0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[day,],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        for(Widget button in buttons)
          button
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

Now when i use a wrap widget with axis set to horizontal, the buttons are placed at the center right position and keeps overflowing from there on. I've tried using align widget,but it does not work either. EDIT: I know that there are calendar plugins for flutter that are very easy to use, but my use case is a little different, and I'd not like to use any calender plugins  .

Comment: Do they send content to next line?

Comment: Wait, so what was your question?

Comment: Pls add screenshot (or hand drawing) of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The `Wrap` widget didn't work because the parent(`Row`) doesn't have boundaries.

And its confusing that why you have to use `Column` inside a `Row` just to display a day of the week.

Use `GridView` instead of nesting `Row`, `Column` and `Wrap` to build your calendar.